# React native app crashes after uploading the apk on google play store, it crashes only for the first time

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-play

I am working on an app using react-native. After generating Apk using `./gradlew assembleRelease` everything works fine. But when I upload the apk on google play store and installs, it crashes only for the first time. And gives the below error.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError
Interface com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzge implemented by class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver' appears in base.apk)
java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass (VMClassLoader.java)
java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass (ClassLoader.java:738)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:363)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:84)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3482)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:207)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1759)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6863)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:537)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have tried changing proguard-rules.pro

```
# firebase
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; } 
-keep class io.invertase.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.invertase.firebase.**
```

I have also tried adding this code inside AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<receiver
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This issue is not coming with release apk being directed installed and checked but only happens when apk is uploaded on play store and downloaded for the first time.

I have been trying this for a couple of days now. I would be glad if someone helps me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to this problem. This was not related `proguard` rules but due to the version mismatch of using firebase and google libraries. Check all the `gms` libraries version and `firebase` library version and use the versions which are mentioned to be used together. Checkout google libraries [release version](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_27_2019) and [support libraries version](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages).